# Extremely slow wifi

Tags: wireless, mac, macbook

I'm having an issue with my wireless network connected to my home wifi. It's wpa2 protected and after 1-10 minutes of wifi usage my connection speed with go from 12mbps to 500kbps. If i stop and start my wifi it will speed up again for another 1-10 minutes. I'm using an early 2011 Macbook Pro and wifi works fine on the Mac partition and on my fiance's chromebook. This issue first appeared when I installed VirtalBox but I uninstalled VB and formatted my entire HD and re-installed the OS. I'm running an early 2011 Macbook Pro on Ubuntu 14.10. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: install [`nethogs`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-find-out-what-process-is-using-bandwidth/) to see which process is using up your bandwidth after 10 minutes of use.

Comment: What command should I run with that?

Answer (score 0):

[Nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/) is a utility that will allow you to monitor which running processes are using your internet bandwidth. This way you can track why it's slowing down.

To install it on Ubuntu, use this command

```
sudo apt-get install nethogs
```

Once it's installed, you need to find the name of your wireless interface. In most cases, this is called `wlan0`. To make sure, run

```
iwconfig
```

to list your wireless network interfaces. Once you know the name, you use nethogs like this:

```
sudo nethogs wlan0
```

Once in nethogs, press `r` to sort by data recieved, `s` to sort by data sent, `m` to cycle between display modes (kb/s, kb, b, mb), and `q` to quit.

Hope this helps you find the faulty process that is hogging your network.

Comment: nethogs shows no significant programs using resources other than chrome.